# FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AdroidManifest

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set permissions to facebook login ("email"), however i am getting this error:

```
Xamarin.Facebook.FacebookException:Log in attempt failed:FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AdroidManifest.
```

This is where i encounter my error:

```
// After facebook,google and all identity provider login completed 
auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(activity, new string[] { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }); //Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR!!!", ex.ToString(), ":(");
        }
```

I have defined my Android manifest as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="LoginSystem.Android">
  <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.email" />
  <application android:label="LoginSystem.Android" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="LoginSystem" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:name="md50ef850b548eeb6d8287c9a52e2084363.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" android:name="md50ef850b548eeb6d8287c9a52e2084363.SplashActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="Intervention-X">
    </activity>

    <service android:name="md59f70a99687498e7ba187118950981d26.KeepAliveService" />
    <activity android:label="Web Authenticator" android:name="md550f8a10a740eb4fb6376baab8337ce22.FormAuthenticatorActivity" />
    <activity android:label="Web Authenticator" android:name="md550f8a10a740eb4fb6376baab8337ce22.WebAuthenticatorActivity" />
    <activity android:name="md511f2fcf685a3847eee0baf2c814b548d.MediaPickerActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="LoginSystem.Android.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.LoginSystem.Android" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1" />
</manifest>
```

Also, i have 2 `Manifest.xml` files for some reason. Don't know the location for the one that i just attached but the original one is in its original place (under Properties), and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="LoginSystem.Android">
  </application>

  <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
 android:label="Intervention-X" />

</manifest>
```